# Numpy-like interface to dynamic lists

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python library that provides lists which can be grown dynamically without a lot of overhead (in contrast to `numpy` arrays, which have to reallocate their entire memory if you append to them), but at the same time provide a `numpy`-like interface, support advanced slicing (e.g. `data[:,1]`) and the like.

Perhaps something as simple as *approach (3)* in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7134033/2748899), but with a bit more polish.